# Filter according to several columns and thresholds specific to each (in R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with ~600 columns. I would like to group my dataframe according to a variable and filter on `n` of these 'columns of interest' (usually a small proportion of the total number of columns) according to a threshold specific to each column and group.

I've started doing this using dplyr. I'll use the `iris` dataset (as I'm unoriginal) to demonstrate:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Petal")), 
            funs(threshold = quantile(., 0.5) - IQR(.)))
```

This calculates my threshold (per group and per column) and puts them in new columns called `Petal.Length_threshold` and `Petal.Width_threshold`.

```
# A tibble: 150 x 7
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal.Length_th…
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa              1.32
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa              1.32
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa              1.32
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa              1.32
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa              1.32
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa              1.32
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa              1.32
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa              1.32
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa              1.32
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa              1.32
```

What I want to do now is check that for each row, ALL columns of interest are greater than their respective (group and column) threshold. I've done this like so:

```
columns <- colnames(
iris %>% 
  select(starts_with("Petal"))
)

threshold_cols <- paste(columns, "threshold", sep = "_")

filtered_iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Petal")), 
            funs(threshold = quantile(., 0.5) - IQR(.))) %>%
  filter(UQ(as.name(columns[1])) > UQ(as.name(threshold_cols[1])) &
           UQ(as.name(columns[2])) > UQ(as.name(threshold_cols[2])))
```

(Note the `UQ(as.name())` is due to the annoying dplyr non-standard evaluation making it difficult to input a column name as a variable into dplyr functions).

The problem is that I would like to generalise this (as I want to write a re-usable function) so that it is able to compare any number of 'columns of interest' with their respective (group and column) thresholds. I am able to find out how many columns of interest I have in every case using `starts_with()` and it would be the length of `columns` in the above code.

Also writing out `UQ(as.name(columns[1])) > UQ(as.name(threshold_cols[1]))` is ugly and time-consuming so any suggestions as to how to improve this would be greatly appreciated as well.

I have attempted this by writing my own function to add to the end of a dplyr pipe. The function has turned out extremely hacky and difficult to read but here it is:

```
columns <- colnames(
iris %>% 
  select(starts_with("Petal"))
)

threshold_fun <- function(x){

  # obtain only columns of interest
  reduced_x <- x[,columns]

  # create empty threshold vector
  threshold <- vector(mode = "numeric",
                      length = length(columns))

  # fill vector with the threshold
  # result should be a vector of 2 (in this case) with the
  # Petal.Length threshold then the Petal.Width threshold

  for (i in 1:length(columns)){

    print(i)

   threshold[i] <- quantile(reduced_x[,i], 0.5) + IQR(reduced_x[,i])

  }

  # for each row check that all elements are greater than 
  # threshold. Result should be vector of TRUEs and FALSEs
  filter_rows <- apply(reduced_x, 1, function(a)
    sum(a > threshold) == length(columns))

  # subset using vector above
  filtered_x <- x[filter_rows,]

  return(filtered_x)

}

my_filter <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  threshold_fun()
```

This gives me an error `Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing`. I have tried adding `print()` statements to try to figure out where in this function the problem occurs and it appears to be in the for loop. This alone gives the above error: `quantile(reduced_x[,i], 0.5)`.

My question is, how do I either generalise the first dplyr code or fix my function?

**EDIT**

Great answer by Calum You but in case it is useful for anyone wondering across this in future, I have managed to make my function work:

```
columns <- colnames(
iris %>% 
  select(starts_with("Petal"))
)

threshold_fun <- function(x){

  # obtain only columns of interest
  reduced_x <- x[,columns]

  # create empty threshold vector
  threshold <- vector(mode = "numeric",
                      length = length(columns))

  for (i in 1:length(columns)){

    threshold[i] <- quantile(reduced_x[,i][[1]], 0.5) - IQR(reduced_x[,i][[1]])

  }

  # for each row check that all elements are greater than threshold. 
  # Result should be vector of TRUEs and FALSEs

   filter_rows <- apply(reduced_x, 1, function(a){
     sum(a > threshold) == length(columns)}
     )

   # subset using vector above
   filtered_x <- x[filter_rows,]
   # 
   return(filtered_x)

}

myiris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(threshold_fun(.))
```

- `reduced_x[,i]` returns a dataframe whereas `reduced_x[,i][[1]]` returns a vector. A vector is required by functions like `mean` and `quantile`
- Adding `do()` (`do(threshold_fun(.))`) ensures that groups are respected and the function is performed on groups of your dataframe instead of the whole dataframe (as when piping directly to `threshold_fun()`). More info [here](http://www.milanor.net/blog/dplyr-do-tips-for-using-and-programming/)

(Yes, this is an absurdly long question now)

Comment: What exactly do you want to be able to pass to this function? A list of column names, or since you just are finding columns with `starts_with` anyway are you ok passing that as an argument?

Comment: Apologies, I should have specified - the variable I wish to group by and the string to put into `starts_with()` to find the columns of interest are the same each time. So this function should only need to take the df as the argument.

Comment: @JPL: can you explain what threshold `quantile(., 0.5) - IQR(.))` measures, statistically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a lot of tasks like this where I find myself using `mutate_at`, it's often easier to generalise by `gather`ing the data and using different groupings to achieve what I want to do. Here's an example that accepts a character `starts_with` argument as a selector for "columns of interest", since you say "I am able to find out how many columns of interest I have in every case using starts_with()".

Basically, we can put all the columns we are interested into `colname` and `value`. This makes each new row an oldrow-column combination. Then we can calculate the threshold without needing to resort to `mutate_at` by including the `colname` in the grouping. To `filter` the results, we group on the `rowid` instead of the colname and use `all` (so for every original row, if any of the values in the columns of interest exceed their respective thresholds, all the values in that row are dropped). Finally, we can `spread` back out and clean up the temporary variables we created.

Example with `"Sepal"` argument and with `mtcars` as well.

```r
library(tidyverse)
filter_threshold <- function(df, group_col, starts_with){
  group_col <- enquo(group_col)
  df %>%
    rowid_to_column() %>%
    gather(colname, value, starts_with(starts_with)) %>%
    group_by(!!group_col, colname) %>%
    mutate(threshold = quantile(value, 0.5) - IQR(value)) %>%
    group_by(rowid, !!group_col) %>%
    filter(all(value > threshold)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-threshold) %>%
    spread(colname, value) %>%
    select(-rowid)
}
iris %>% filter_threshold(Species, "Petal")
#> # A tibble: 122 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5 setosa           1.4         0.2
#>  2          4.9         3   setosa           1.4         0.2
#>  3          4.6         3.1 setosa           1.5         0.2
#>  4          5           3.6 setosa           1.4         0.2
#>  5          5.4         3.9 setosa           1.7         0.4
#>  6          4.6         3.4 setosa           1.4         0.3
#>  7          5           3.4 setosa           1.5         0.2
#>  8          4.4         2.9 setosa           1.4         0.2
#>  9          5.4         3.7 setosa           1.5         0.2
#> 10          4.8         3.4 setosa           1.6         0.2
#> # ... with 112 more rows
iris %>% filter_threshold(Species, "Sepal")
#> # A tibble: 121 x 5
#>    Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#>           <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1          1.4         0.2 setosa           5.1         3.5
#>  2          1.4         0.2 setosa           4.9         3  
#>  3          1.3         0.2 setosa           4.7         3.2
#>  4          1.4         0.2 setosa           5           3.6
#>  5          1.7         0.4 setosa           5.4         3.9
#>  6          1.5         0.2 setosa           5           3.4
#>  7          1.5         0.1 setosa           4.9         3.1
#>  8          1.5         0.2 setosa           5.4         3.7
#>  9          1.6         0.2 setosa           4.8         3.4
#> 10          1.4         0.1 setosa           4.8         3  
#> # ... with 111 more rows
mtcars %>% filter_threshold(cyl, "d")
#> # A tibble: 26 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl    hp    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb  disp  drat
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6   110  2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4  160   3.9 
#>  2  21       6   110  2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4  160   3.9 
#>  3  22.8     4    93  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1  108   3.85
#>  4  18.7     8   175  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2  360   3.15
#>  5  14.3     8   245  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4  360   3.21
#>  6  22.8     4    95  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2  141.  3.92
#>  7  19.2     6   123  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4  168.  3.92
#>  8  17.8     6   123  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4  168.  3.92
#>  9  16.4     8   180  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3  276.  3.07
#> 10  17.3     8   180  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3  276.  3.07
#> # ... with 16 more rows
```

Created on 2018-10-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works a charm! In the line `group_by(rowid, !!group_col)` - I noticed that you only need to `group_by(rowid)` as this groups the group_col's separately anyway.

Also any thoughts on why I got the error in my `threshold_fun`? `i` should just a number and not 'matrix or array'? It's still bugging me...

Comment: Not having tested, my guess is `filtered_x <- x[filter_rows,]` since `filter_rows` is coming out of `apply` and is probably a matrix

Comment: I don't think you need  `group_by(rowid, !!group_col) %>% filter(all(value > threshold))`. Try the simpler `ungroup() %>% filter(value>threshold)` instead